# How to send a handleSubmit on react hook form in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am doing a form sign-up using typescript and react, however, I am facing a typing error when I try to submit handleSignup function. Here is my code:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { api } from "../../services/api";

export const Signup = () => {

    const schema = yup.object().shape({
        name: yup.string(), 
        email: yup.string(),
        password: yup.string(),
        address: yup.object().shape({
            zipCode: yup.string(),
            number: yup.number(),
            complement: yup.string(),
        })
    })
    
    interface signUpCredentials {
        name: string 
        email: string
        password: string 
        address: {
            zipCode: string 
            number: number 
            complement: string 
        } 
    }

    const {
        register,
        formState: { errors },
        handleSubmit,
    } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema)
    })


    const handleSignup = ({ address, email, name, password }: signUpCredentials ) => {
        api
            .post("/users/signup", { address, email, name, password })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("Created")
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Not created")
            })
    }

    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSignup)}
        >
            <input
                {...register("name")}
                placeholder="name"
            />
            <input
                {...register("email")}
                placeholder="email"
            />
            <input
                {...register("password")}
                placeholder="password"
            />
            <input
                {...register("address.zipCode")}
                placeholder="zipCode"
            />
            <input
                {...register("address.number")}
                placeholder="number"
            />
            <input
                {...register("address.complement")}
                placeholder="complement"
            />
            <button type="submit" >
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

The problem that I am facing is exactly *

> onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSignup)}

- 

I am receiving:

> Argument of type '({ address, email, name, password }: signUpCredentials) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubmitHandler'.
> Types of parameters '__0' and 'data' are incompatible.
> Type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'signUpCredentials': name, email, password, addressts(2345)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not specified the type variable `signUpCredentials` to the `useForm` hook, and you should change the `onSubmit` handler to `handleSignup` and call the `handleSubmit` inside that. So, your code should look like this,

```js
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { api } from "../../services/api";

export const Signup = () => {

    const schema = yup.object().shape({
        name: yup.string(), 
        email: yup.string(),
        password: yup.string(),
        address: yup.object().shape({
            zipCode: yup.string(),
            number: yup.number(),
            complement: yup.string(),
        })
    })
    
    interface signUpCredentials {
        name: string 
        email: string
        password: string 
        address: {
            zipCode: string 
            number: number 
            complement: string 
        } 
    }

    const {
        register,
        formState: { errors },
        handleSubmit,
    } = useForm<signUpCredentials>({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema)
    })


    const handleSignup = handleSubmit(data: signUpCredentials) => {
          console.log(data)
          // do api stuff here
    }

    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={handleSignup}
        >
            <input
                {...register("name")}
                placeholder="name"
            />
            <input
                {...register("email")}
                placeholder="email"
            />
            <input
                {...register("password")}
                placeholder="password"
            />
            <input
                {...register("address.zipCode")}
                placeholder="zipCode"
            />
            <input
                {...register("address.number")}
                placeholder="number"
            />
            <input
                {...register("address.complement")}
                placeholder="complement"
            />
            <button type="submit" >
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

For a better understanding, I created a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-brahmagupta-09dizp?file=/src/index.tsx) link where I have removed the `import` statement to services as we don't have that, and you can see the function is called without any warnings/errors by checking the console.

[image: Edit loving-brahmagupta-09dizp]

Ref: [React Hook form (TS)](https://react-hook-form.com/ts/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the `onSubmit` as mentioned by @sri-vineeth.
Just use `SubmitHandler` type.

```
const handleSignup: SubmitHandler<SignUpCredentials> = ({ address, email, name, password }) => {
  ...
}
```

Also please note that interfaces and types should use PascalCase. Therefore change `signUpCredentials` to `SignUpCredentials`.